# How To Run Exe File From Asp.net project which is host on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to run .exe file from mvc application which is host on iis 
when i enter url (of host .net application) in browser exe run.

my .exe file is on server and i want from there every user use this exe file instead of install on all user pc

need sample code to run exe from mvc application

Comment: Please provide some more detail and any code you have; It will help others help you.

Comment: You simply `Process.Start` it. It will run with the same set of permissions and capabilities as the code running in IIS does. I get the feeling you will be disappointed though because it will only have access to the web server environment, not the users. The normal reason for providing an exe rather than a web app is because it needs some deep level of access to the users machine. But if it's only an exe that takes some arguments on the command line, does it's work and quits then you might be satisfied

Comment: below code work on server but not work from client browser. 
  
    var MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" ) ;  
    MyObject.Exec("D:\\Projects\\DF_Projects\\Dlls\\FieldSupportUtility.exe");

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. It would be a massive security issue. All the methods which did let you do this are long obsolete as they were abused for malware etc.

You just want to let the user download the file and then ask them to run it.